# Cannot install due to memory being exhausted and duplicated software

Tags: installation, administration

I have a problem with a Joomla! site that I did not build.  It is due to memory being exhausted.  When I try to install I get this message:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24576 bytes) in /home/xxxxxx/public_html/libraries/src/Table/Nested.php on line 1340

I'm sure it is not a memory issue as I have raised the memory limit (in the hope that I would be able to update Admin Tools and Akeeba Backup at least whilst I troubleshoot).

Previous to this, I had a problem with duplicate IDs in the extensions table.  I manually updated these by using phpMyAdmin to download a CSV and update all the duplicate 0 IDs with incremented numbers.

I have disabled any extensions that I don't recognise except Joomla! Core.

I have reuploaded via FTP all the latest Joomla! files.

When I look in extensions > Manage, I find multiple copies of things like F0F3 and even templates like Beez and Hathor.  Uninstalling them removes them all, so I'm keen to avoid that.

Firstly, how can I remove the duplicates?  My guess would be that duplicate extensions would take a lot more memory if all being activated at the same time.

I see multiple copies of the Akeeba in the extensions table, but I don't see it in the admin menu.  The same with Admin Tools.

The Admin tools plugin does not seem to exist.

I'm concerned this is a hacked site if I'm honest.

Comment: do you have an option to start with a clean install and just migrate the content and template across. If you are going to end up responsible for this site in the future it might be better to have confidence in the base site.

Comment: with the FOF3 you should be able to uninstall it and all the Akeeba packages and once you know it is all gone, then installing any of the Akeeba packages should install just one version for you.

Comment: looking at the code around your error message it suggests to me that you are getting into some type of recursive loop that I don't think you ever leave so not sure any amount of memory is going to solve it for you. There is not a lot to go on, but your history of messed up tables and duplicates would have me thinking it is problem caused by data in one of those tables.

Comment: Thanks. U fortunately there are custom apps on the site that I didn't make or else I would rebuild the site. I'm not sure what else to do

Comment: Maybe if I do an Akeeba kickstart and instead or dropping the tables I update the. That might work

Comment: I am not sure a Kickstart will work in not dropping the tables. What back up are you going to use as the input and is that going to update entries or create new additional duplicates for you?

Comment: Good point. If install a fresh Joomla! What's the easiest way to copy the tables but leave the non cores intact? I don't have access to all of the extensions which is my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this problem due to a huge session database table.

I would recommend having a look at the database using phpmyadmin, Sequel Pro or similar.  Have a look at the {prefix}_session table, if it has 10s of thousands of rows or more then it is likely that your problem is caused by this.

First step would be to truncate this table, it is safe to do so.  The only negative would be that any currently logged in users would be forced to login again.

This would hopefully get the site running again.  I'd then recommend installing and activating the core session purge plugin to prevent the issue from recurring.

Comment: It's a small site, front end works, but that would be a concern if true. But I'll try it

Comment: Definitely worth ruling out.  Even with a small site, if affected by this problem, the session table will continue to grow until it hits an unmanageable size. Good Luck!

Comment: I emptied it, although it did seem full, that didn't solve the problem for me.  But I also have other issues such as in Joomla! update extensions appear multiple times

Answer (score 1):

@Eoin If the extensions have been Installed via the normal Joomla process then there should be a manifest file in the /administrator/component/com_customapp that you can start with to rebuild an installation file and do an Export of the SQL Table(s) from the bad environment. 
Create a fresh install of Joomla somewhere and try installing the rebuilt installation file until you get all the bits to make it work and then Import the related tables into the fresh Joomla and I think you should have a workable environment as far as the custom apps go.

Comment: So long as the custom apps aren't the problem :)  Although I disabled them all and tested and the issue still persists.  Would you consider that to mean it must be in core?  If so this annoying job might be worthwhile :)

Comment: I'm thinking that perhaps if I drop all of the core extensions from the original database, then create a new Joomla! in a new database and then copy the tables over that would be quickest.  The files for the extensions I do not posses and I've already overwritten the core so that might be the quickest way.

Comment: The files for the custom extensions must be in the Joomla instance or they wouldn't be working and most will be in ../administrator/components/com_customapp/ and if it has a front end component then it would be ../components/com_customapp and there will probably be a couple of language files but the /com_customapp/customap.xml file should tell you what bits were installed. Once you have created the installer file then you will have it for life and be able to install it anywhere.

Comment: I think manually editing tables and dropping in updates is what has probably create the mess you have in the first place, so even if you fix this particular issue with what you are suggesting, I feel you will be forever fixing issues with this instance of Joomla and never be confident it is right. Your comments suggests that you are wanting to drop tables from a new installation of Joomla over the top of your current Live site, correct?

Comment: If that is correct, at a minimum I would suggest getting a back up and trying out that idea in a test environment first or you could be further up the creek with less means of propulsion very quickly.